# Where is the appropriate place to discuss Solar Power installations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

With the proliferation of sustainable energy, more and more people are building home solar power plants, both on-grid and off-grid.   RVers do this routinely.  If there is not a specific place to post information about the technical details of these systems, perhaps it could be created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a Stack Exchange dedicated to [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) and they do some support on [the installation of solar panels](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/fusing-a-solar-pv-panel).

Your specific question might already be asked; I'd recommend to browse through the 80 questions tagged [solar-panel](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-power) first. As always, please read their [help center](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

There are also 48 questions about [Solar Panels](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-panels) on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) so it might be worth looking there as well as on [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/).